# Is it possible to add some characters near number contained into a String?

Tags: regex, actionscript

I want to know if is possibile through regularexpression, count the numbers contained into a string and add a specified character near it.

For exemple, this is a string: Hello2all821abc13
This string contain 3 numbers: 2, 821 and 13 (note that the numbers contained into 821 and 13 are considered like an unique entity, not signle). I want to add near each of it the "-" symbol. Is it possible?

Comment: This is Objective-C? And what does "near" mean? Do you want `-` before and/or after the number?

Answer (score 1):

You can add dashes by replacing `/(\d+)/` with `"-$1-"` 
which surrounds each match with dashes.

Since AS Regex does not support lookbehinds, you may then have to remove dashes at the beginning/end of the string by replacing `/^-|-$/g` with `""`, if you don't want those.

- \d means digit (0-9)
- + means one or more
- ^ means the start of the string
- $ means the end of the string
- | means OR

You can get the number of... err, numbers by searching for `/(\d+)/`

Comment: don't work.. i've wrote this in actionscript3:

var prova:String="asfds123asd34asd23"
var rr:RegExp=/(d+)/ 
prova=prova.replace(rr, "$1-")
trace(prova)

The result is
asfd-s123asd34asd23

Comment: var prova:String="asfds123asd34asd23"
var rr:RegExp=/(d+)/g
 
prova=prova.replace(rr, "\1-")
trace(prova)

but the result is asf1-s123as1-34as1-23
(it have placed dash near the first number

Comment: the result is asfds\1-asd\1-asd\1-
it delete the number and replace it wit "1-"

Comment: i've discovered that the correct syntax to replace the match with the same match + "-" is: $1- . If i want to add the dash at beginning of the number too, what i've to write?

Comment: I've updated my answer above and deleted all comments since they may be misleading (due to the /(d+)/ typo and such).